# GCE : Snapshot restore vs Disk Image

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Will restoring a snapshot recreate the environment EXACTLY as it was at the point of the snapshot?  I am specifically referring to the operating system and installed software.

If not, then I assume that a disk image is a correct approach

Answer (score 1):

Snapshot and Disk Image use the same process. Both take a point in time copy of a storage device by performing a block copy.

Will either restore exactly (bit-for-bit) as the source? Yes, if you shutdown the VM instance. Maybe if you do not. Google (and AWS, Azure, etc.) strongly recommend that you shutdown your VM before these types of operations. The reason is that file system data could be cached in memory that has not been flushed to disk. A snaphot requires that all applications and the OS participate in the snaphost process. Few applications do.

Comment: Tx v much.  I am processing windows updates and need a rollback point in case there are issues with the patches